# combine sprintf arguments

Tags: php, printf

I have a question about using sprintf in php.

An equation returns a value of 0.6 but I always want it to display as three decimal places like so:

> .600

As the data changes, it may result in something like: 0.567443 but I'd like it to display as:

> .567

Always three decimal places, and never with a leading zero. I tried using `sprintf('%00.3f',$percentage)` but that didn't work. It always places the leading zero.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have right now and it at least does 0.600 but yes, the leading zero is there.

Comment: Yep. Then... replace it. I see no way to not out leading zero, using only `sprintf`.

Comment: `%f` is according to your locale settings. Probably it's possible to change the locale so it does drop even the leading 0. Or [do it the string way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9709776/367456).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One might call this cheating:

```
sprintf('.%0-3.3s', $percentage * 1000);
```

But it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
sprintf('%.3f',$percentage)
```

Don't include the leading zero in the format string, doing so enforces that it *must* have a leading zero.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have right now and it at least does 0.600 but yes, the leading zero is there.